# Custom Web Site Client / Bot

Tags: windows, desktop-client

I need a software to monitor changes on the sites which I have account instead of using a web browser. Assume I have a forum account at xyz.com. The software must login to the site, and show me if I have new messages, if there are new posts and replies to my posts (as shown on the site). I guess I'll need to give the software html codes like:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox default-value" name="vb_login_username" id="navbar_username" size="10" accesskey="u" tabindex="101" value="User Name">
```

Here name and value field should be defined. That's just an example for inputs, in most cases captcha will be needed but cookies (auto logins) will handle this.

<strike>I'm using Live Helper Chat Client for Live Helper Chat system but this doesn't satisfy me. I also need similar one for other sites like forums. Is there a tool to create desktop client for web sites? Here's a screenshot:</strike>

I prefer free or open source but any other options would be fine. My OS is Windows 10 x64 and Linux is my alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org)** can simulate web user. It purposed for automated testing web sites, but can be used for automation.

Pro:

- python can be used for programming
- deep browse integration (up to use specific version of browser)
- handle sites which hard to automate (javascript, live DOM modification, ajax, Flash ...)

Con:

- Complex dependencies
- strict bound to specific OS version (recommended usage VM or container)

---

**[Scrapy](https://scrapy.org)**

> An open source and collaborative framework for extracting the data you need from websites.
>
> In a fast, simple, yet extensible way.

Pro:

- Simpler install (relative to Selenium). Just python module.
- special for data extraction (but can reach out of limits)

Con:

- Problem with sites which modify DOM by javascript

---

PS.
Site redesign can break Your custom client. Some services struggle to avoid alternative clients.

Comment: I couldn't try either programs yet but there's one answer. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I just share experience.